# Keep record of duplicates

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, revisions-list

Once upon a time when question was closed as a duplicate, the message containing the other question details was injected to the closed post itself and was integral part of it that appeared in its Revisions.

When such question was reopened, we could see in its history (revisions) what exactly happened and what was the question(s) it was closed as duplicate of.

Now with the change in duplicate close mechanism, the questions body stay intact and the messages are pushed separately as part of the display only. If duplicate question closed with the new mechanism is reopened, there is no trace for the other question(s) anymore. [Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/167267/revisions).

I would like to still have that information; not that it's extremely useful or valuable, but we did have it before and it's nice to have.

Two options come to mind:

1. Add the dupe question(s) in the revisions page itself e.g.

   > Post Closed as "exact duplicate" **of [other question here]** by Kate Gregory, hims056, Manishearth, Rosinante, BoltClock's a Unicorn♦
2. Undelete the auto generated comments on the question when it's reopened.

Comment: 1st option is appropriate. Because auto-generated comment can be deleted any time by the first close voter.